# long data type on method accepts an int

Tags: c#, types, int, long-integer

Consider this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int input = 10;

    Console.WriteLine(GetResult(input));
}

static string GetResult(long input)
{
    return (input).ToString();
}

static string GetResult(int input)
{
    return (input).ToString();
}
```

As it stands, the code in the `Main()` method will call the second `GetResult()`, which accepts an `int` parameter. If I delete the second method, it will automatically use the first method, which accepts a `long` parameter.

Whilst I can understand that an `int` as an `Int32` will fit within a `long` as an `Int64`, I was unable to find an explanation (to assist my curiosity) as to how this works underneath the hood.

Should I just accept that it just works or can someone provide more details?

Comment: It will be converted implictly. See [Implicit numeric conversions table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table).

Comment: Implicit type conversion! Oh, and overload resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one needs to read the specs about how method overloading works in the language. When there is more specific signatures matching method available it would be called. In the above case as `Int` can implicitly be converted/upcast to `long`, if there is no overload taking an `int` it would end by calling the other overload which is taking `long` as input.

For example:

```
int a  = 1;
long b = a; // compiles due to implicit conversion
```

Also refer to the following docs link to lookup the implicit conversion between types in C# posted in comment by [@Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table

The following post should be helpful in understanding how overloading resolution works in C#

https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Overloading

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Fildor sure i can add that